# What is the correct way to send a jwt token from server side to client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api, jwt

Long winded but I'm using Googles Youtube v3 Data API node.js package to sign in users and view playlists and such. Currently when a user successfully logs in with googles Oauth redirect flow a route server side is called which passes in a code by url query parameters. I'm able to parse that out, generate a token with my oauth2Client and then create a signed jwt. Right now I redirect the user to a url that has the signed jwt as a url query parameter which is then parsed out browser side and stored as a token in the local storage, this is my first time using anything related to jwts and want to be certain that I am doing things in a secure way. Being such I'm not entirely sure that how I am sending the token server side to client side is the proper way and not quite sure where to start looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in response like `res.cookie(key, value)`

Comment: res.cookie('token', token), then calling res.redirect(302, response.url) seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple way to pass token from server side to client side

1) you can pass token in your response
2) you can pass token in response header

Answer (score 2):

It is not the right way. If the server is responding to an XHR request (coming from javascript), then the server can send the JWT in the body of the response. If the server is responding a regular browser request (GET or POST, but not handled by javascript), then it's easier to just put the JWT in a cookie.

Comment: Ok yes, after doing some research it looks like I can basically call res.cookie() then res.redirect() and it will simplify things. I will need to test this out when I have a sec.